# GWT RequestFactory occasionally Illegal Argument Exception

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, requestfactory

I'm giving the first steps with the GWT Request Factory and I'm having an occasionally exception. What I find strange is that it doesn't happen in every server request...just sometimes.

The exception is:

```
>      Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Something other than a Java object was returned from JSNI method
> '@com.google.web.bindery.autobean.gwt.client.impl.JsniCreatorMap::invoke(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)':
> JS value of type boolean, expected java.lang.Object
```

I get an error when I call:

```
> Request<List<ConcertProxy>> findAll();
```

Which is implemented like this:

```
public static List<Concert> findAll()
{
    Objectify ofy = ObjectifyService.begin();
    List<Concert> concerts = ofy.query(Concert.class).limit(100).order("-id").list();/* this dumps to memory */
    return concerts;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing to do with RequestFactory, this is a Chrome DevMode Plugin bug. Google recommends using Firefox (or IE) for DevMode: http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5778#c65